# apostrophe-cms toolbar with floats

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've been putting together a site with apostrophecms, however I've come to the point with one of the layouts where it just doesn't play nicely.

The content is a simple mixture of p and img tags (floated left or right)

Toolbars for images floated to the left are ok, but the toolbar for any right floated images is positioned on the wrong side of the document.

Is there a good way to resolve this without building the layout in a different manner?

Alternatively I could use the rich text editor, however the image item in the rich-text module only allows the use of an image from a URL, and does not include a way to upload the image directly into the system (that I can see).

Thanks for your help!

[Sample screenshot of what's happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OhJe.png)

```
  &#story-detail {

.wrapper-relative {
    section {
      overflow: visible;
      max-width: none!important;
       text-align: left;
       q {display: block; font-size: 1.3em; margin: 1em auto;}
       q, p, h5 {width:60%; margin:1em auto; z-index:5}
       div {overflow: visible;}
       img {
        position: relative;
        &.left {float:left; margin-left: 5%; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 30px; max-width: 400px }
        &.right {float:right; margin-right: 5%;  padding-left: 20px; padding-bottom: 30px;  max-width: 400px}
        &.full { margin:0; width: 100%;  }
       }
}
```

}

}

```
<section class="{{ data.widget.animationType }}">
    {{ apos.area(data.widget, 'areaMain', {
      widgets: {
        'apostrophe-rich-text': {
            toolbar: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Split',  'Link', 'Unlink']
        },
        'simple-image': {}
      }
    }) }}
</section>
```

Comment: Can I see the CSS you are using?

Comment: i've added the SCSS for the appropriate section, thanks Tom.

Comment: Are the images and text content separate widgets within the same area? (IE. apostrophe-images and apostrophe-rich-text)

Comment: Yes 2 different widgets within the same area. - Code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to float the entire widget, not just the visual content (`img`). Give your widget a custom class that leverages a piece of schema to give yourself the different widget modifiers.

In your widget schema add

```
{
  name: 'float',
  label: 'Float',
  type: 'select',
  choices: [
    { label: 'None', value: 'none' },
    { label: 'Left', value: 'left' },
    { label: 'Right', value: 'right' }
  ]
}
```

And then in `lib/modules/simple-image-widgets/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
  construct: function (self, options) {
    self.getWidgetWrapperClasses = function (widget) {
      return ['simple-image--' + widget.float];
    };
  }
};
```

Now your entire wrapper will have a class that know to float, the controls should go with the container.

Comment: That makes total sense, adding a class to the widget works a treat. Thanks.

Comment: Just noticed that this is (obviously) only called on construct of the widget. So If I change the class of the image the widget classes are not added unless the page is refreshed. How can I call this on widget update too? Is it a case of having to add it to the self.play method from always.js, or is there a better way? Cheers.

Comment: Yes, to react to changes during editing you probably want to reinforce the class modifier within the widget's play method, looking at the data object it is passed. Sounds like you're familiar with this pattern but if not https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/custom-widgets.html#adding-a-java-script-widget-player-on-the-browser-side